# Prolog: nested list

Tags: list, prolog

I have this Prolog code:

```
pick_number_simple([],[]).
pick_number_simple([H|T],[H|T2]):- 
    number(H), pick_number_simple(T,T2).
pick_number_simple([H|T],T2):-
    not(number(H)), pick_number_simple(T,T2).
```

which gets the numbers out a list. For example:

```
pick_number_simple([d,f,7,5,e,3,g], NumList)
```

gives you:

```
[7,5,3]
```

But I want to make it get the numbers off of a nested list.

For example:

```
pick_numbers_general([a,b,1,[2,[c,3]],d],1,NumList)
```

Would give you:

```
[2,3]
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Wait. What means "make it get the numbers off of a nested list"? And what should do second argument of pick_numbers_general/3 ?

Comment: as in to get the numbers out of a nested list for example if i have this pick_numbers_genera([a,b,1,[2,[c,3]],d],1,NumList). and i want to get Numlist = [2,3].

Comment: From nested list *only*? What for "1" is in this example?

Comment: it doesn't have to be nested list only, and 1 is a number that if the output sis greater than it, then the predicate is true.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it what u need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U may use [flatten/2 predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2)

```
pick_number_simple([],[]).
pick_number_simple([H|T],[H|T2]):- 
    number(H), pick_number_simple(T,T2).
pick_number_simple([H|T],T2):-
    not(number(H)), pick_number_simple(T,T2).

pick_numbers_general(List, Num, NumList) :-
    flatten(List, NestList),
    pick_number_simple(NestList, NumListAll),
    findall(X, (member(X, NumListAll),X > Num), NumList).
```

So

```
?- pick_numbers_general([a,b,1,[2,[c,3]],d],1,NumList).
NumList = [2, 3] ;
```